# PHP Ratchet Websocket Server With Apache2 Not Working

Tags: php, linux, websocket, apache2, ratchet

I have a websocket server written in php, it's the Ratchet websocket server.
I enabled wstunnel for apache. I also added ProxyPass in my website configuration

This is my apache configuration for my website.

```
 <VirtualHost *:443>
 DocumentRoot /var/www/mywebsite/pav/
 ServerName www.mywebsite.com
 ServerAlias mywebsite.com

 RewriteEngine on
 ProxyPass /wss2/ ws://www.mywebsite.com:8080

 
 <Directory /var/www/mywebsite/pav/>
 DirectoryIndex index.php
 AllowOverride All
 Order allow,deny
 Allow from all
 </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

My website is written php and JS.
In javascript the script I used to connect to the server is

```
 var socket = new WebSocket('wss://www.mywebsite.com:8080');
```

I checked in my browser (Firefox) using inspect and in the console it says:
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://www.xpatvoice.com:8080/.

I've tried other browsers and got the same result.

The thing is I don't know how to tell what's causing it to fail,
I mean any error code or error log to diagnose the problem.

I also tried

```
 var socket = new WebSocket('wss://www.mywebsite.com/wss2/:8080');
```

Here's the chat socket class

```
namespace MyApp;

use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;


class Socket implements MessageComponentInterface {

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
        $this->users = [];
        $this->inqs = [];
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {

        // Store the new connection in $this->clients
        $this->clients->attach($conn);

        echo "New connection! ({$conn->resourceId})\n";
        //echo $conn->httpRequest->headers["X-Forwarded-For"][0];
                
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
        
        $data = json_decode($msg);
        $userinfo = json_decode($data->userinfo,true);

       if(isset($userinfo["userId"]) && $data->action == "userLogin"){
                $userID = $userinfo["userId"];
                $this->users[$userID]["conn"] = $from;
                $this->users[$userID]["role"] = $userinfo["role"]; 
                echo "attached user $userID\n";
           
           // NOTIFY INQUISITORS OF ADMIN LOGIN
                if($userinfo["role"] < 3){
                    foreach($this->inqs as $inq => $client){
                        $message["action"] = "adminLogon";
                        $client->send(json_encode($message));
                    }
                 } 
       }
        
        if(isset($userinfo["userId"]) && $data->action == "adminReply"){
            
            $this->inqs[$data->to]->send($msg);
            
        }
        
           if(isset($userinfo["tempuser"]) && $data->action == "enquiry"){
                $userID = $userinfo["tempuser"];
                $this->inqs[$userID] = $from;
                echo "attached inquisitor $userID\n";
          }
        
        if(isset($userinfo["tempuser"])){
            
            foreach($this->users as $userid => $user){
                if($user["role"] < 3){
                    $user["conn"]->send($msg);
                }
            }
            echo "message from inquisitor\n";
         }
        

    }

    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {

      $this->clients->detach($conn);

    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
    }
}
```

I enabled proxy, proxy_wstunnel, proxy_http
with

```
        sudo a2enmod proxy
        
        output: Module proxy already enabled
        
        sudo a2enmod proxy_wstunnel
        
        output: Module proxy_wstunnel already enabled
        
        sudo a2enmod proxy_http
        
        output: Module proxy_http already enabled
```

I'm using Apache/2.4.41

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow (SO). it looks like you have a connection issue. As far as the code you've posted is involved, you're hidding all Exceptions of that connection. Are there any exceptions? And if there are, what arre they? You find an [edit] button beneath the question to do so.

Comment: And I do not find any documentation that echo is supposed to work within onOpen(). Please provide a reference for this kind of usage, best from the Ratchet documentation.

Comment: You report that you enabled wstunnel, in the light of the connection issue, how did you verify it works? Edit your question and provide the information, e.g. the command you've run for verification, it's output and your interpretation/understanding of it.

Comment: As far as I know I didn't put any exceptions for the connection. I downloaded the script for ratchet socket server from github. I did get the socket server working before on another one of my websites and echo worked when I initiated the socket server from the command line using php, anytime someone connected to the server it would display the message,  "New Connection". Thanks btw for the help

Comment: Please see the deprecation notice in the begining of https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_wstunnel.html - Which apache version are you using? Please add the info to the question (e.g. at the bottom).

Comment: Okay I didn't know this but I'm using Apache/2.4.41

Comment: Then this does not apply. Troubleshoot before you change the configuration (do not upgrade yet).

Comment: Do you mean I should run journalctl -xe before I change the website.conf file?

Comment: well locating the right log-files and inspecting them can yield you some more information, however it is better to know about the correct logfiles first. in your case I would double-check the apache error log, that is a) for apache and b) if PHP runs within apache then that is also the PHP SAPI logger for errors unless you configured a different PHP error log. You can also add calls to error_log() within your php code to leave messages, `echo` is not appropriate for that, use the error log for diagnostic messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I followed hakre's advice and looked at the php/apache error log located in /var/log/apache2/error.log
and this error came up whenever I tried to connect to the socket server from a browser.

`AH00898: DNS lookup failure for: www.mywebsite.com:8080 returned by /wss2/:8080`

I googled it and found my answer in this link here

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/240590/why-is-apache-giving-dns-lookup-failures

As it turns out the error was in the apache configuration for my website.